# Computing the Lebesgue Integral of $\int_{[1, \infty)} \frac{1}{x^2} \; d\mu$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to compute the Lebesgue integral of $\int_{[1, \infty)}  \frac{1}{x^2} \; d\mu$. I don't think MCT can be used here. Based on the answers to this similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200637/lebesgue-integral-int-1-infty-frac1x?rq=1), I thought that I should use DCT, but I am not sure how to find a suitable function that bounds the sequence of functions that converges pointwise to $\frac{1}{x^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the sequence $f_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{x^{2}}\chi_{[1,n]}$, where $\chi_{[1,n]}$ is the indicator function of $[1,n]$. This sequence satisfies the hypotheses of the DCT, and you can compute the integrals $\int f_{n}$ using Riemann integration. You therefore get that $\int_{[1,\infty)}\frac{1}{x^{2}}dx=\lim \int f_{n}$.

Let's check the hypotheses:

First, $f_{n}$ is measurable since the function $\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous in $(0,\infty)$ (hence measurable) and $\chi_{[0,1]}$ is measurable (since $[0,1]$ is too). Therefore $f_{n}$ is measurable as the product of two measurable functions.

Second, let $x\in [1,\infty)$. take $N\in \mathbb{N}$ to be the least integer greater than or equal to $x$. The sequence $(f_{n}(x))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is given by: $f_{n}(x)=0$ if $n< N$, $f_{n}(x)=f(x)$ if $n\geq N$. This sequence is increasing and convergent to $f(x)$, as desired.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think it is better to argue that the sequence fulfills MCT, in that way you do not have to provide an independent proof that $1/x^2$ is integrable in $[1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 3):

The function you try to integrate is continuous and positive so your Lebesgue integral is the same thing as an improper Riemann integral.
So : $\int_1^{+\infty} 1/x^2 dx=[-1/x]_1^{\infty}=1$

Comment: If you doubt this answer will be accepted, include a proof that the Lebesgue integral agrees with the Riemann integral wherever both are defined.

Comment: So for example $\sin(t)/t$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: I was not aware that Reimann integration is equivalent to Lebesgue integration even in the case of improper integrals.

Comment: The case of improper integrals is somewat tricky: there are Riemann integrable functions on $(0,\infty)$ which are not Lebesgue-integrable. Nevertheless, if the function in question has constant sign and is Riemann-integrable, it is also Lebesgue integrable (and both integrals are equal). The proof of that statement is the same as what I sketched in my answer.

Comment: They are equivalent for absolutely convergent improper Riemann integrals.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich: no because in that case the Riemann integral is not absolutely convergent. This is a basic counterexample.